# Are there advantages to joining PMI before paying for/taking PMP exam?

Tags: pmp, pmi-framework

I had read somewhere that you can receive a discount on the PMP exam fee if you are a PMI member, but this seems debatable when you consider that you need to pay for the membership.  Other than a digital copy of the PMPBOK, have any of you found benefits in having the PMI membership?  Also, is it required to join a local PMI chapter when getting a membership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register for the exam as a non-member, it costs $555.  To register as a member, it is $405, so the $150 difference is more then the $129 member registration.  You are saving $21 and getting a membership for free.

You get a digital copy of the PMBOK, which can print if you prefer.  You also get a subscription to their magazine either digital or print edition with project management articles.

You do not have to register for a local chapter.  It make sense to register for the national membership simply because you are saving $21.

Comment: I find that the digital copy on a tablet is easy to read and was extremely helpful in passing the PMP test.

Answer (score 3):

You also get access to the Practice Standards i.e. additional material on everything from estimating to scheduling. Very helpful.